# Graphing the binomial coefficients: appearances?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

Is it appropriate to describe the function
$$f(x) = \binom{x}{2}$$ as parabolic?
How does it vary over $c$:
$$f(x) = \binom{x}{c}?$$
And, is there any intuition behind these graphs? For example, their resemblance to the polynomials of degree $c?$

I tried inputting one into wolfram alpha and it spat out a continuous function, which confused me. This is what prompted me to ask the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can generalise the factorial, choose function, etc. to not whole numbers too.
$$\binom{x}{k}=\frac{x!}{k!(x-k)!}$$
$$=\frac{x(x-1)\dots(x-k)!}{k!(x-k)!}$$
$$=\frac{x(x-1)\dots(x-k+1)}{k!}$$
So for $k=2$ you will get:
$$\binom x2=\frac{x(x-1)}{2!}=\frac{x^2-x}{2}$$
And for $k=3$:
$$\binom x3=\frac{x(x-1)(x-2)}{3!}=\frac{x^3-3x^2+2x}{6}$$
And so on.

Comment: To add: the polynomial that shows up in the numerator of these expressions is what's often called a *falling factorial*, $x^{(k)}$. Thus, we have the relationship $\dbinom{x}{k}=\dfrac{x^{(k)}}{k!}$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $B_c:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ defined by
$$n\mapsto {n\choose c}$$
is a polynomial of degree $\min(c,n-c)$. So it is "parabolic" (assuming you mean quadratic) when $c=2$ or $c=n-2$.

And be careful when you define functions, it is of good habits to specify the sets where it is defined as well as the image set.

If you want a function defined for real $x$, search for an analytic continuation of the binomial.

Answer (score -1):

I have usually used the binomial formula with discrete whole numbers. If you want to plot this, you get points on a grid.

$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$

Comment: So, it is not appropriate to enter in real number into x? I tried inputting it into wolfram alpha and it spat out continuous functions, which confused me. This is what prompted me to ask the question.

Comment: It can be extended to real numbers with the gamma function, and in this case it has an obvious extension to polynomials.

Comment: The binomial formula can be written as $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. Taking factorials require the input to be an positive integer value.

Comment: @MarkR you can generalise the factorial for complex numbers too... See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Comment: @MarkR For example, $i!$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorial(i)

Comment: Neat, I have not seen it being used in that way before. Learn something new every day.

Comment: if the binomial is defined through the falling factorial (as in Botond answer) then you do not need to invoke gamma, and $\binom{x}{q}$ is a polynomial of degree $q$, for $0 \le q \in \mathbb Z$

Comment: "The binomial formula is not a continuous function." False! if all the points of the domain are isolated, the function is trivially continuous,